# In CommCare can my question labels in my data export to be set to a non default-language?

Tags: commcare

My application is set to deploy to a default language (Chichewa), but I would like to access the question labels in English when I set up my case and form data exports. All my questions are translated into English. Can I set my export to pull in the question labels in English instead of the default language?

Answer (score 1):

The question labels are currently only available in the default language in CommCare